# How to apply Opacity for object and Textura separately?

Tags: textures, opacity

I put text on the sphere. In my code below the Opacity[0.6] is applied for both. I want to make a sphere with Opacity[0.6] but text with Opacity[1]. How to make this?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 Sin[t] Cos[f], 2 Sin[t] Sin[f], 2 Cos[t]}, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, 
{t, 0, Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[.6], Texture[ImageReflect[ImagePad[Rasterize[
Style["Text", FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica",Black, Background -> None,
Opacity[1]],Background -> None], {{800, 100}, {120, 100}}, "Fixed"],Top]]]}]
```